# Devise setup errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm having issues setting up devise in a fresh rails app. I've just created a fresh Rails app, added the devise gem and ran `bundle install`. Now when I try to run `rails generate devise:install` I get this error:

```
/Users/Bobo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:557:in `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming.
```

I'm confused, I haven't even touched my routes file yet, when I run `rake:routes` it says: `You don't have any routes defined!`

Why am I getting this error? It is literally the first step I took..

Edit: my routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # root 'welcome#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Comment: What does your `routes.rb` look like?

Comment: Did you add `devise` right after creating a new rails app or did you change anything anywhere?

Comment: It was the first thing I did. Since that was it, I created another fresh rails app in a new directory and then everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. But if it works now it's all good I guess :)

Comment: Yea it is, thanks for lending a hand!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any routes defined, they are all commented out. Uncomment the root route e.g. change

```
  # root 'welcome#index'

  root 'welcome#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install in a new directory, no more problems.

Answer (score -1):

Change your routes. As mentioned above set the **root**
Make sure you have a controller called **WELCOME** with template and action **'index'** 
Then root => welcome#index will point to that action.

Run

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Run

```
rails g devise Model
```

This will automatically add routes for your Model to the routes.rb file

Run `rake db:migrate` OR with rails5 `rails db:migrate`
Than you have create a Model with Devise.